# Writing out ARCore position data? (Augmented Faces)

Tags: arcore

Hi I'm pretty new to ARCore, and I've been able to get Augmented Faces working but I can't figure out how to write out the data, or if there even is a way (which seems strange if there isn't). I really love the results and I would love to use the data for performance capture, but I cannot find a way to record and export.

I've spent the entire day digging around and trying things, the most I've found is someone used TCP to stream the data over the network to their PC, but when trying it I found there's issues with latency and the data still has to be recorded on the client end so it only solves part of the problem.

If anyone has any knowledge of this and could help point me in a direction I'd be super appreciative, ty!

Answer (score 0):

Well, presuming your app was based on Google's sample code:

arcore-android-sdk-1.22.0/samples/augmented_faces_java

then its based on this open source:

https://github.com/javagl/Obj

which has this example on "how to write out the data" here:

Obj-master/src/test/java/de/javagl/obj/TestObjWriter.java